# Adding missing glyphs to fonts

Tags: fonts, software-recommendation, glyphs

I need to add extended characters (š,č,ř,ž,ě) to a font. I can do this in Photoshop, but can you please recommend me a program that has this functionality + can save it as a font that I can use on the web?

Thanks and sorry for a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would want to make your characters into vectors, and then use IcoMoon to generate the font: http://icomoon.io/

Edit:
Or you could try http://www.glyphsapp.com/

Comment: I'm preferably looking for software which loads up the whole font family and let's me add the missing glyphs. Please let me know if you know about anything that could work like that..

Comment: aha, I see. Then you might want to try http://www.glyphsapp.com/

Comment: I'm on Windows, but it looks like there's a program called FontForge which should have the same functionality as GlyphsApp. Thanks!

Comment: Well, so I was not all that helpful :-) glad you found a solutions though.